# Fourier-Transform of $\frac{x^{\alpha}}{1+x^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis

Does anybody know a way to compute the Fourier-transform $F(y)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-i xy} f(x) dx$ or Cosine-Transform $G(y)=\int_{0}^{\infty} cos(xy) f(x) dx$ of the function 
$$
f(x)=\begin{cases} \frac{x^{\alpha}}{1+x^2}, & x>0 \\ 0 & else \end{cases},
$$ 
where $\alpha \in (0,1)$?  Basically, I'm only intersted in the asymptotic behaviour as $y \to \infty$ of $F(y)$ or $G(y)$ in terms of decay rates. For further calculations I would need that $F(y)$ or $G(y)$ are contained in $L^1(\mathbb{R})$. If anybody knows a good reference where to find this (or a similar) calculation, that would already be enough. I think that the result for $G(y)$ mentioned in standard integral tables like Erdelyi *Tables of Integral Transforms. Part 1.*(here it would be formula (1.3.6) on page 11) is wrong, since it is unbounded as $y\to\infty$ (there occurs a summand which behaves as $\cosh(y)$). This can't be the case since $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ and therefore $F(y) \to 0$ as $y \to \infty$.

Comment: The Fourier transform of a function in $L^1$ tends to $0$ for $|y|\to\infty$.  See Rudin *Real and Complex Analysis* 9.6.  The value for $y=0$ is pretty simple, $F(0)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\,dx$, and $F$ is continuous too.  Does that answer your question about asymptotic behavior?  Or do you want an estimate of how fast $F(y)$ goes to zero?

Comment: @ForgotALot: Indeed, an estimate about the decay rate of $F(y)$ would be what I'm looking for. I would need that $F \in L^1(\mathbb{R}$ for further calculations, but I don't know if that is true or how to prove or disprove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is enough to apply Theorem 5.4. from the article *The Wiener algebra of absolutely convergent Fourier integrals: an overview* by Liflyand, Samko and Trigub, to show, that $f(x)$ has integrable Fourier Transform. There are various other Theorems contained in this article, that apply to this situation.